# Sitecore log file breakdown into 50MB chunks

Tags: sitecore, log4net, sitecore6

In our produciton system log files are pretty big (300MB etc.). I need smaller files to do analysis, I need these Sitecore log files to breakdown into 50MB chunks, how can I do this?

Sitecore 6.6

Answer (score 2):

can you try to modify log4net in web.config file ? 
    You will have :

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
  <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/log.{date}.txt"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>

  <!--Add this property maximumFileSize  -->
  <maximumFileSize value="50MB" />

  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="WebDAVLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
  <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/WebDAV/WebDAV.log.{date}.txt"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: A really good set of tutorials for log4net that explains all the various options with good examples: http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorials-and-Resources.aspx